# Spring MVC server takes 188268 ms to restart. How to deal with it?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

Every time I so much as change one line in a controller of my Spring MVC app, it takes about `188268 ms` to restart the server before I can test my change.

Is my app configured wrong? Is there a way to make it only reload the controller I've modified, not the whole app?

Note: I'm developing in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) which seems to restart my server after it detects a change to any file, recompiling the whole thing apparently.

Comment: You should provide more details. How many beans are instantiated on  application-startup? How performant is your development workstation ? Are you using Hibernate with many Entities ? ... Wrt reloading only the class you have changed, a hot-class reloading  tool like e.g. JRebel (it has a free social plan) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already hidden in your own phrase.

> it takes about 188268 ms to restart the server before I can **test** my change.

If you want to test your change you should write a unit or integration test for your controller and run that on every change you make. No need to restart any server whatsoever.

Comment: I do this all the time and it works great. The extra benefit is having a actual test to rely on as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into these [recommendations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization) of how to speed up the startup of a Spring application.

The recommendations are made by Google App Engine but are applicable to any spring application. Usually a part of the problem is that too many classes are being scanned.

You can also try to see why the application is taking so long by starting it from your IDE, and pausing it with the debugger a few times and see what it's doing (is it scanning components, etc.).